# WPF application does not run on some PCs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF application runs fine on some PCs, on others it crashes before log4net starts logging. The Error is

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: gui.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 55cd97ed
  Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18408
  Problem Signature 06: 52312f13
  Problem Signature 07: 7fe8
  Problem Signature 08: ee
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
```

The PC has .NET-Framework 4.5.1 installed, my 32-bit application is .NET-Framework 4.5. I have noticed that, on another pc where it did not work, the application worked after installing Visual Studio 2013.

I'd be very thankful for a tipp on what I might be missing.

Comment: Maybe you are using some extension dll's which come with Visual Studio, but .NET framework does not contain them?

Comment: When installing the application, is there a difference in the install folder? e.g. missing .dll's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing  VC++ 2013 x86 redistributable on other Win32 PCs should solve the problem.

Comment: Download and install VC++ 2013 redistributable from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784) . Your application might use some internal dll's so it is necessary  to install redistributable on the other PC that does not have Visual studio installed in it